# How to add two variables on the x axis in a ggplot2 graph (bar and scatterplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graph a bar chart with a scatter plot over it and have not been able to get it to show up successfully.

I keep getting the error code --- Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot

```
plot(ggplot(midwest, aes(state, poptotal))+
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="tomato2")+
  xlab("State")+ylab("Total Population"))+
par(new=TRUE)+
plot(ggplot(data = midwest) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = popwhite, y = poptotal)))
```

I would like to have the scatterplot show up over the bar graph but it is just not showing up.

Comment: Your code is not correct. See this tutorial http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-essentials

Comment: You're off to a good start but as Tung suggested it might help to build up piece by piece going through some ggplot tutorials. One thing that might help you is that the function `ggplot` returns a ggplot object. You can store these objects in variables, in lists, etc. but you do not *need* to wrap `ggplot` with `plot` or anything else; when written correctly the default behavior is to print the "ggplot" in your default graphing device. Finally, in ggplot2, I believe the idiomatic way to specify a secondary axis is with `sec_axis`: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html. The exam

Answer (score 0):

From your description I imagined you might have been going for something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#midwest is a dataset included in tidyverse

dat<-midwest %>% group_by(state) %>% summarize(poptotal=sum(poptotal), popwhite=sum(popwhite))


dat$state<-factor(dat$state, levels=dat$state[order(dat$poptotal)])
dat %>% ggplot(aes(state, poptotal))+
    geom_col()+
    geom_point(aes(y=popwhite), color="red")+
    theme_classic()
```

[image]